# in Xamarin How to change frame of superview when constraints are added to subviews programatically?

Tags: ios, xamarin, autolayout, mvvmcross

TopView : Superview, 
Subviews in topview :  confirmImage,confirmationInfoView, visitLabelContainer, noteTextLabel, dashboardButton.

contentContainer : Superview of TopView

Constrains added to topview :

```
topView.AtLeftOf(contentContainer),
topView.AtRightOf(contentContainer),
topView.AtTopOf(contentContainer),
topView.Height().EqualTo(444),
```

Constraints Added to subview of topView :

topView.AddConstraints(

```
confirmImage.WithSameCenterX(topView),
confirmImage.AtTopOf(topView, 27),
confirmImage.Width().EqualTo(94),
confirmImage.Height().EqualTo(94),

confirmationInfoView.Below(confirmImage, 28),
confirmationInfoView.WithSameCenterX(topView),
confirmationInfoView.Width().EqualTo(284),
confirmationInfoView.Height().EqualTo(116),

visitLabelContainer.Below(confirmationInfoView, 3),
visitLabelContainer.WithSameCenterX(topView),
visitLabelContainer.Width().EqualTo(138),
visitLabelContainer.Height().EqualTo(19),

noteTextLabel.AtBottomOf(topView, 29),
noteTextLabel.WithSameCenterX(topView),
noteTextLabel.Width().EqualTo(343),
noteTextLabel.Height().EqualTo(36),

dashboardButton.AtBottomOf(topView, 87),
dashboardButton.WithSameCenterX(topView),
dashboardButton.Width().EqualTo(347),
dashboardButton.Height().EqualTo(44)
```

);

If i change frame height of topview it doesn't change anything.
If i change bounds height of topview it changes frame 'y' to negative. (half of a height).

Can anyone please suggest me how to change frame in xamarin when constrains are enabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you have set the autolayout, the frame will be useless. `topView.Height().EqualTo(444)` this code will change the topView's height, what effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Land Lu - MSFT Thanks for your reply. I want to change the height of topview on button click (Where button is subview of topview), After changing the bounds of  topview i.e. topView.Bounds = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(topView.Bounds.Left, topView.Bounds.Top, topView.Bounds.Width, topView.Bounds.Height + 174);  it decrement topview's y and changes alignment of subviews into topview. does not maintain constraints to subviews in topview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used autolayout to place your control, you should modify the 
height constraint to change the height of topview:

```
foreach (var constraint in contentContainer.Constraints)
{
    if (constraint.FirstItem == topView && constraint.FirstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Height)
    {
        constraint.Constant += 174;
    }
}
```